# Adding a png to an existing pdf with php (mPDF)

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am trying to add a custom signature to an existing pdf document.

When I try added a PNG document it just gives me a little square 'x' mark where the picture should be. If anyone can spot what I am doing wrong please let me know.

```
$mpdf->Image('signature', 25, 200, 210, 297, 'png', '', true, false);
$mpdf->Output('newpdf.pdf');
```

[errorimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKyfy.png)

Comment: Check the [overwrite](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/overwrite.html) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That symbol usually indicates an image not found.

You are not specifying the filename adequately, p.s. that image size looks big, try, then adjust as needed.

```
$mpdf->Image('path/to/signature.png', 25, 200, 80, 50, 'png', '', true, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!